# Is "sololy" the correct usage?

Tags: word-request

I saw https://www.powerthesaurus.org/sololy, which indicates that "*sololy*" means 
"*solely*", "*lonely*", is that correct way of saying it?

The word "***solo***" has a meaning of "*one and only*". I'm interested in its adj and adv form. For e.g., some companies assign an unique customer service representative (CSR) to each customer. They can say,

In *adj* form:

> We've assigned a *solo* CSR to you.

Now, in *adv* form, what the following is more correct?

> The CSR is for you *sololy*.

or

> The CSR is for you *solo*.

?

**UPDATE**, The preferred way of saying:

> The CSR is for you *solely*.
>
> The CSR is *solely* assigned to you.

Comment: I've never heard the word "sololy" used in either spoken or written.  Usually the adverb meaning "one and only" is **alone**: "The CSR is for you alone."

Comment: "Sololy" is not a word in English.  The adverb is *solely*.

Comment: Added another case that "_alone_" will sound awkward: "**The CSR is _solely_ assigned to you**"

Comment: Right, the word does not exist. People who use it just don't know. It shows lack of education. Sole is not one and only. One and only =sole. Solo means  you are doing something alone (without others). A solo performance [music, dance, etc.] A solo (on the guitar, piano, etc. To do something solo means to do something alone.

Comment: Oh, good to know @Lambie, that "_Solo is not one and only. One and only =sole_". Thx

Comment: Yes, and that's why it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo can be either an adjective or an adverb, thus 'sololy' is a mistaken formation. I would not use the word in any kind of serious writing. I found only one dictionary that includes it, and that was a dictionary of slang. Power Thesaurus is 'crowdsourced', and I would not consider that a recommendation for an English learner seeking standard English guidance.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sololy

Regarding using 'solo' in the sentence "The CSR is for you solo", I would prefer 'solely' or 'alone'.

Comment: "Solo" is also a verb and a noun.  *Quadruple*-threat!

Comment: Possibly worth noting that (in my opinion, at least) "alone" seems much more natural in that context than "solely".

Comment: @rococo, please see my added case.

Comment: Oh yes, he soloed this afternoon [flying].